# Java выводит already in use: bind, но порт не занят

Tags: java, netty

Выводит ошибку BindException: Address already in use: bind, хотя порт не занят.

TCPView не показывает, консоль тоже.

Даже перезапуск системы не помог.

В чём проблема? (port: 80)

Comment: Проблема в том, что порт занят. Какая ОС используется?

Comment: Windows 8.1, но почему-то консоль и TCPView не выводят, что этот порт открыт

Comment: А в консоли как смотрите?

Comment: Я пишу netstat -ano

Comment: Так а почему вы смотрите порт 80, если jetty разворачивается на порту 8080 по дефолту?

Comment: Но до этого на порту 80 у меня всё работало, после неизвестной мне махинации всё сорвалось и порт навечно остался занятым, даже после перезапуска.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80435/discussion-between-enderbro3d-and-roman-danilov).